# Inspect **existing** websockets in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, websocket

I know you can inspect new websockets in Chrome via Network, but what about existing sockets? Let's say you open the devtools after the websocket was created. Some data has been sent and received already (don't care), and now I want to inspect the rest. Can I? Who browses with devtools always open? I want to inspect the current page's Websockets, without reloading of course.

I made this, but it requires at least 1 `socket.send`, and not all websockets do that:

```
(function() {
  var s = WebSocket.prototype.send;
  WebSocket.prototype.send = function(json) {
    if (!this._oh) {
      this._oh = 1;
      this.addEventListener('message', function(e) {
        console.log('receive', e.data);
      });
    }
    console.log('send', json);
    return s.apply(this, arguments);
  };
})();
```

Using a bookmarklet or remote script is fine. I know an extension could do it (by overriding all `WebSocket` on every single page), but I rather not.

Comment: you found a way to do?, I'm looking for the same

Comment: @wZVanG No, not beyond the code I posted. It's still a (rarely used) bookmarklet. I wish Chrome would log ALL frames when devtools is open.

Comment: What you're doing is injection and is possible. I'm also seeing this, the console displays only the frames, but for me, the only solution is to edit the Chrome own since I am using Chrome extensions. Today or tomorrow I will post a new question about this with bounty.